# Align form radio button in fixed size table column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, forms

I have to recreate an old form using latex. It includes a table where multiple questions are associated to some radio buttons.

I managed to create most of the form and table using `hyperref` and `array`, but now have a problem in the horizontal alignment of the radio buttons. As you can see in the screenshot the radio buttons are not center-aligned, but somewhat shifted to the right.

**How to center-align the radio buttons in the 3 right columns?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\noindent\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular} {|m{8cm}|C{0.75cm}|C{0.75cm}|C{1.5cm}|}
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    Yes & No & Maybe \\
    \hline
    Some question? &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=yes} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=no} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=maybe} \\
    \hline
    Some other question? &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=yes} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=no} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=maybe} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with your code i can't reproduce your image. the radio buttons are not visible. it seems that something is missing in code.

Comment: @Zarko strange - I just literally copied over the above to code to a new project and recompiled it. Still the radio buttons show up (Foxit reader). I'm using Miktex on Windows here.

Comment: i use MikTeX too, but for viewer Sumatra. i didn't check other pdf viewers.

Comment: I get nothing visible when viewing with mupdf, red squares when viewing using evince, grey squares with a red circle only in the chosen option in opera browser (linux), so I guess it's a viewer issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\LayoutChoiceField{<label>}{<field>}` controls how your radiobuttons are printed and is predefined to the effect of

```
\newcommand*\LayoutChoiceField[2]{#1 #2}
```

Note the space between label and field. This space shifts the field to the right in your table. Just redefine

```
\renewcommand*\LayoutChoiceField[2]{#1#2}
```

to get rid of it. (You could even leave out `#1` if you never ever wanted to use a label, but I'd leave it in for clarity.)

---

The typesetting of the radio button itself also adds some spaces, too. This is done by `\@@Radio`, which adds several `\space`s. We can prevent this by locally making `\space` do nothing (using `etoolbox`):

```
\pretocmd\@@Radio{\begingroup\let\space\@empty}{}{}
\apptocmd\@@Radio{\endgroup}{}{}
```

I do not know if this might have any unintended consequences, but I can't think of any right now.

---

All in all your MWE now looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\LayoutChoiceField[2]{#1#2}
    \pretocmd\@@Radio{\begingroup\let\space\@empty}{}{}
    \apptocmd\@@Radio{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\noindent\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{tabular} {|m{8cm}|C{0.75cm}|C{0.75cm}|C{1.5cm}|}
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    Yes & No & Maybe \\
    \hline
    Some question? &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=yes} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=no} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q1, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=maybe} \\
    \hline
    Some other question? &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=yes} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=no} &
    \ChoiceMenu[ name=Q2, radio, radiosymbol= ]{}{=maybe} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks. This improves the result by a few pixel. However, the radio fields are still not quite center-aligned [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/9H0zEdI).

Comment: Looks like I didn't check the result carefully enough. I edited my answer accordingly.